# Is the Proto-Slavic root *term (dwelling) related to the Proto-Ugric root *tärɜ „open space, room”?

Tags: etymology, slavic-languages, turkic-languages, romanian, hungarian

I am curious about the obscure etymology of the Romanian word [*tărâm*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C4%83r%C3%A2m) (realm, domain, world, geographical space -- usually a poetic word, like in the plural form *alte tarâmuri* = "other (foreign) realms", or in folktales:  *de pe celălalt tărâm* = "from the other world" - "otherworldly").

[Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C4%83r%C3%A2m#Etymology) says: Probably of eastern origin. Cf. Hungarian [terem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terem#Hungarian), Turkish [tarım](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tar%C4%B1m#Turkish); possibly of ultimately Arabic origin."

There are multiple hypothesis in fact and I was skeptic about each of those presented. Initially I dared imagine one myself from Latin *territorium* (*tărâm* could be written *tărîm* -- and that was the official form until 1991). (Some Romanian linguists tried to integrate *tărâm/tărîm* to the *terra > țară (country, land)* semantic family (along with *țărână* = dirt, earth, *țăran* = peasant, even dubiously *țarină* = crop field, and *țărm* =shore, etc, but as far as I can tell without a connection to the semantically and even morphologically close *territorium*.)

Anyway, the Arab origin is not probable at all, it entails an Ottoman Turkic transmission, but I could´t find a convincing connection, given that the Turkish word means "agriculture". I was doubtful about the Hungarian connection too, given that the Hungarian *terem* means hall, chamber, room, itself apparently [coming from Slavic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terem#Etymology_1): Bulgarian трем (trem, “hall”), Ukrainian терем (terem, “hall”), Serbo-Croatian trijem/тријем (gate), Old Polish *trzem*, also the famous [Russian terem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terem_(Russia)#Etymology), which is something like a harem.

A harem may be "otherworldly" in a way, I told myself, still not convinced. But what really seduced me was the Hungarian word [tér](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9r#Etymology_1), which surprisingly covers most aspects of the Romanian *tărâm*. So, [terem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terem#Hungarian) must come from [tér](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9r#Etymology_1), I imagined. In fact no! The former is related by Wictionary to the series of Slavic terms coming from the [Proto-Slavic root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC#Bulgarian) *term (dwelling), while the latter to the [Proto-Ugric root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9r#cite_note-2) *tärɜ „open space, room”.

There is also the Cuman connection: based on [Codex Cumanicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Cumanicus), looking for Romanian words of Cuman origin, the linguist Emil Suciu (*Cuvinte românești de origine turcă* [*Romanian words of Turkic origin*], p. 215–225, cited by Boerescu in [*Etimologii românești controversate*](https://www.academia.edu/33673691/ETIMOLOGII_ROM%C3%82NE%C5%9ETI_CONTROVERSATE_IPOTEZE_%C5%9EI_SOLU%C5%A2II_2017_full_text_)[*Controversial Romanian etymologies*], p. 420) has added the word *tărâm* to his list of suspects, based on the Cuman term **tarïm*, meaning "(crop) field", therefore close to the Hungarian semantic area of interest and something which is historically probable: Cumans, Hungarians and Romanians have lived close to each other (and mingled) long enough (Wallachia was initially called Cumania, and [even now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumania#Kuns%C3%A1g_and_the_Catholic_Diocese_of_Cumania) some regions of Hungary bear the name of the Cuman).

So, a Hungarian-Cuman hypothesis for the etymology of my word seems to me the most probable. The Turkic connection can be reduced to the Cuman: the Cuman language was Turkic, so there is no need to hypothesize about Anatolian origins of that word.

But how to integrate the Slavic connection? Is there a relation between the Proto-Slavic root **term* (dwelling) and the Proto-Ugric root **tärɜ* „open space, room”?

I find very odd that the Hungarian suggested base (*térem*) for the Romanian word is not etymologically based on *tér*, although Hungarian has [the suffix *-em*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-em#Hungarian) to [create nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Hungarian_noun-forming_suffixes) (albeit usually with verbs it seems). (I wonder: is *térem* a result of suffixing of *tér*?)

Comment: The Croatian dictionary linked to on the Wiktionary page for _trem_ putatively connects the Proto-Slavic root _*termъ_ (not _**term_) to Greek [τέραμνον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/τέραμνον#Ancient_Greek), which (despite what Beekes says) has an adequate Indo-European etymology from [_*treb-_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/treb-) ‘build; live, dwell (in)’. That root has led to other words referring to larger spaces, like Albanian _trevë_ ‘region, province’, but none that go through the Greek word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I will look into it,  Albanian connections are especially promising when it comes to Romanian etymology.

Comment: As for whether PIE _*treb-_ and PU _*tärɜ-_ are related, it doesn’t look like it at first glance – and relationships between PIE and PU root are shaky enough in general that it’s usually hard to say one way or another.

Comment: Albanian link leads nowhere in this case it seems. Looking in Orel: https://i.imgur.com/RMnH4iE.png. But the fact that there is a semantic stable connection between "space" and "dwelling" (that is, closed and open space) is interesting. Maybe I could conclude that there is that stable connection *within* both PIE and PU, without a necessary connection *between* the two. As for the most probable etymology for my Romanian word, I bet on the Cuman-Hungarian alliance.

Comment: Yes, Wiktionary mentions that as well. I don’t know why he considers a loan meaning ‘truce’ more likely than an inherited root meaning ‘(place to) dwell’, and my knowledge of Albanian is far too shoddy to tell if there are phonological grounds for it – but I will say that what I’ve read by Albanologists often disagrees with Orel on many points.

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss Ottoman "agriculture" like that, see *economy* apparently from Greek "house", akin to English *-wich* in placenames.

Comment: @vectory - the problem is that Romanian words of Ottoman origin usually are concrete, simple, clear (like food, clothing, or military terminology),  are relatively recent, keep the same meaning, and are mostly limited to Wallachia. This cannot be seen in relation to something like *tărâm* at all. If its origin is Turkic it must be older (pre-Ottoman, hence Cuman connection).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - About Orel, the 'truce' part is an embarrassment; but the rest is of no use here either. About `that stable connection within both PIE and PU` - I guess that is too timid a position: (1) the 'open/closed space' semantic nucleus or polarity in both is one thing, but what is intriguing is the morphological similarity. (2) the "open space" meaning is typical to Hungarian-Cuman semantic area (hun. tér=abstract space, even mathematical, rom. tărâm=world) something absent in Slavic area, where "dwelling" is the almost exclusive meaning.

Comment: I always thought that Russian terem comes from Greek. Also compare Russian turma "prison".

Comment: @Anixx russian turma has its origin in turkic türme which also means 'prison'.

Comment: Ukrainian [etymology dictionary](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Етимологічний_словник_української_мови) · [tells](//goroh.pp.ua/Етимологія/терем#22853) about _terem_ so: 1) totally Greek origin; 2) Gr. τέρεμνον «house» ← τέραμνον. Cognates: лат. *trabs*, дкімр. *treb*, гот. *þaúrp*, двн. *dorf*, днн. *thorp*, лит. *trobà*. 3) Other var. is: PS *termъ* ← Gr. τέρεμνον. 4) Wrong comparing: кипч. *tärmä*, Mong. *terme*, калм. *termǝ*. Looks like the last is your case.

Comment: @stegetsj - Sorry, my cyrillic is too bad to read your link. You mean Mong. terme, калм. termǝ is what I'm interested in: what does terme mean in mongol language? - About terem: this says Slavic root, not Greek: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/терем#Ukrainian.

Comment: @cipricus Iʼm sorry, comments has symbol limit here that is why I just copypasted. Kinda full translation: 3) [other Turkic] Kipchak _tärmä_ «womamʼs room», Mongolian _terme_, Kalmyk _termǝ_ «wall». Wiktionary has the 3nd variation, but without explanation where Slavic came from, and thereʼre no source.